# Exibir BLOB texto

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, firebird

Estou com o seguinte problema, em um relatório preciso exibir um campo do pedido que está como BLOB. E quando executo a busca ele retorna um código estranho em vez das informações do campo.

```
$sql = ibase_query("SELECT CAST(OBSERVACAO AS CHAR(80))
                            FROM TB_PEDIDO_VENDA
                            WHERE ID_PEDIDO = $id");
      while ($row = ibase_fetch_row($sql)) {
        echo utf8_encode($row[0]);
```

tentei utilizar o cast para exibir mas ainda n foi. Como exibir as informações desse campo blob ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode trocar a função de obtenção dos dados para `ibase_fetch_assoc`. A mesma já possui um parâmetro que faz com que mostre os dados dos campos "Blobs" ao invés dos Ids. Para isso você deve informar no segundo parâmetro: `IBASE_TEXT`.

```
$sql = ibase_query("SELECT OBSERVACAO FROM TB_PEDIDO_VENDA WHERE ID_PEDIDO = $id");
while ($row = ibase_fetch_assoc($sql, IBASE_TEXT)) {
  echo $row['OBSERVACAO'];
}
```